# Capture the Start time of a flow/Pipeline in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

We have recently started using NiFi for data ingestion. All the processors needed to create the pipeline are grouped under one processor group. It is a simple flow picking data from one prefix in S3 and dumping it to another S3. The processors thus involved are, list-S3  ->  Fetch-S3 -> Put-S3

What I need is that when we start the processor group, then I want some way to capture the start timestamp of the processor group, which is available to us in the processors. I tried to look inside the data provenance but did not find any attribute which would give me this information.

I want the Pipeline start timestamp to be available in the Expression language in the processors that are used.

Comment: There's a `now` expression available that you could use to track when file is passing updateattribute processor that you could put one of the first in your flow/group

Comment: @daggett thanks for the suggestion- Nifi does not allows adding an updateAttribute Processor at the start of the flow before List S3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.